# Syntax Error- in Sqlite3 code when inserting data in table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, syntax-error

I am writing a code to make a basic table and insert data into it using Sqlite3 in Python 3. The CMD is showing syntax error by putting a pointer at a data set.

```
import sqlite3
conn=squlite3.connect('name.sqlite')
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Ages (name TEXT, age INTEGER)')
cur.execute('INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Cael', 16)')
cur.execute('INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Abiha', 33)')
cur.execute('INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Catrin', 29)')
conn.commit()
cur.execute('SELECT name,age FROM Ages')
for row in cur:
    print(row)
conn.close()
```

This is what the CMD shows:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Cael', 16)')
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you know what is wrong with it please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes for your execute statements, this is causing Python to see `Cael`, `Abiha` and `Catrin` as an expected variable or keyword.

Change your execute statements to use double quotes like so:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Ages (name TEXT, age INTEGER)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Cael', 16)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Abiha', 33)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Catrin', 29)")
```

You could also escape them like so `\'` but the above is better.